# Iterate over dictionary of objects

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, object

I have a dictionary of objects which contains the "Names/Ranges" within a spreadsheet.  As I process the spreadsheet I need to update the value associated with a range.

The class to hold this info looks like this:

```
class varName:
    name = None
    refersTo = None
    refersToR1C1 = None
    value = None
    def __init__(self, name, refersTo, refersToR1C1, value):
        self.name = name
        self.refersTo = refersTo
        self.refersToR1C1 = refersToR1C1
        self.value = value
```

I create the dictionary as follows:

```
staticNames = {}
wbNames = wb.Names
for name in wbNames:
    (nSheet, nAddr) = name.RefersTo.split("!") 
    print "Name:  %s    Refers to:  %s    Refers to R1C1:  %s       Value:  %s  " % (name.Name, name.RefersTo, name.RefersToR1C1, wSheets(nSheet.replace('=', '')).Range(nAddr).value) 
    staticNames[name.Name] = varName(name.Name, name.RefersTo, name.RefersToR1C1, wSheets(nSheet.replace('=', '') ).Range(nAddr).value)
```

It seems to work fine.  I can see the dictionary and contained objects in debug.   When I go back to update the objects within the dictionary based on processing the spreadsheet, I get lost.
I call this function:

```
def updateStaticNames(ws, r, c, val_in, staticNames):
    for sName in staticNames:
        if sName.refersToR1C1() == "=" + ws.Name + "!R" + str(r) + "C" + str(c):
            sName.value = val_in          
    return None
```

`staticNames` refers to the dictionary containing the Name/Range objects.
I am expecting `sName` to contain an object of type `varName`.  But alas it contains a string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `for sName in staticNames:` iterates over the **keys** (it's a dictionary, not a list), so `sName` will be whatever `name.Name` was...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`for foo in some_dict` iterates through the *keys* of a dictionary, not its values.

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
for dd in d:
    print(dd)
# gives a; b; c
```

You probably want to do `for foo in some_dict.values()`

```
for dd in d.values():
    print(dd)
# gives 1; 2; 3
```

Comment: If you need both keys and values, pythonic way is to use `iteritems` for example:  `for k, v in d.iteritems(): d[k].refersToR1C1 = "somevalue"`

Comment: @Ivanhoe right, but in OP's code he never needs the key, only the value.

Comment: yes It is giving me the keys.  Thanks for your kind assistance.  So much for multi tasking

Comment: Since people are still looking at this it's worth pointing out that Ivanhoe's comment is no longer accurate. In modern Python, `iteritems` has been replaced by `items` (`for k, v in d.items(): print(k, v)` gives `a 1; b 2; c 3`)